# No validation by default until fill fields in angular

Tags: angular

I have validation in `register.html` page and handle the `FormGroup` in `register.ts`. How to call validation after fill each field not on load page?

This is my code.

`register.ts` file :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth/auth.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidators } from 'src/app/custom-validators';
     
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-register',
      templateUrl: './register.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
    })
    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
      minLength = { name: 1, email: 10, password: 6 };
      id;
      signupForm;

      constructor(private _AuthService: AuthService, private _RouterActiva: ActivatedRoute, private _Router: Router) {
        this.id = this._RouterActiva.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        const { required, email, minLength } = Validators;
        const { patternValidator, passwordMatchValidator } = CustomValidators;
        const decimal = patternValidator(/\d/, { hasNumber: true }); // To check whether the entered password has a number
        const upperCase = patternValidator(/[A-Z]/, { hasCapitalCase: true }); // To check whether the entered password has upper case letter
        const lowerCase = patternValidator(/[a-a]/, { hasCapitalCase: true }); // To check whether the entered password has a lower case letter
        const specialCharacter = patternValidator(/[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/, { hasSpecialCharacters: true }); // To check whether the entered password has a special character
        this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
          name: new FormControl(null, [required, minLength(this.minLength.name)]),
          email: new FormControl(null, [required, email, minLength(this.minLength.email)]),
          password: new FormControl(null, [required, minLength(this.minLength.password), decimal, upperCase, lowerCase, specialCharacter]),
          confirmPassword: new FormControl(null, [required]),
        },
          {
            // check whether our password and confirm password match
            validators: passwordMatchValidator
          })
      }

      signup() {
        const body = { ...this.signupForm.value, RoleId: this.id }
        this._AuthService.signup(body).subscribe(() => {
          alert("Your account has been successfully created, You can login now")
          this._Router.navigate(['/login'])
        })
      }

      get name() {
        return this.signupForm.get('name');
      }

      get email() {
        return this.signupForm.get('email');
      }

      get password() {
        return this.signupForm.get('password');
      }

      get confirmPassword() {
        return this.signupForm.get('confirmPassword');
      }

    }
```

html:

```html
<!-- <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
        <div id="formContent">
            <!-- Tabs Titles -->

            <!-- Icon -->
            <div class="fadeIn first">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMArry-DDCCYujaUQugB_fA1jXr35M_5ELEQ&usqp=CAU"
                    id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
            </div>

            <!-- Login Form -->
            <form (ngSubmit)="signup()" [formGroup]="signupForm"  >
                <input formControlName="name" required type="text" id="name" class="fadeIn second" placeholder="Name">
                <div *ngIf="name.touched && name.invalid" class="alert alert-danger error">
                    <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">* please enter your name</div>
                    <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength"> * name must be at least {{minLength.name}} characters long</div>
                </div>

                <input formControlName="email" required type="text" id="email" class="fadeIn second" placeholder="Email">
                <div *ngIf="email.touched && email.invalid" class="alert alert-danger error">
                    <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">* Email is Required!</div>
                    <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">* Enter a valid email address!</div>
                    <div *ngIf="email.errors.minlength"> * Must be at least {{minLength.email}} characters</div>
                </div>

                <input formControlName="password" required type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third"  placeholder="password">
                <div *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid" class="alert alert-danger error">
                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">* Password is Required!</div>
                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength"> * Must be at least {{minLength.password}} characters</div>
                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.hasNumber"> * Must be at least one number</div>
                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.hasCapitalCase"> * Must be at least one letter in capital case!</div>
                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.hasSmallCase"> * Must be at least one letter in small case!</div>
                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.hasSpecialCharacters">* password must have at least one special characters</div>
                </div>

                <input formControlName="confirmPassword" required type="password" id="confirmPassword" class="fadeIn third"  placeholder="Confirm Password">
                <div *ngIf="confirmPassword.errors" class="alert alert-danger error">  Password do not match  </div>

                <input [disabled]='signupForm.invalid' type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Sign up">
            </form>

             <div id="formFooter">
                <p>Have an account?</p>
                <a class="underlineHover" routerLink="/login"> Log in now!</a>
            </div> 

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shehadeh, are you asking how to validate the form every time any of the fields have their values modified?

Comment: No, I am asking how to validate any field after fil that field not on load page
so give customer chance to fill field then show validate not on load page

Answer (score 0):

use

```
signupForm.get('name').dirty
```

instead of

```
signupForm.get('name').touched
```